# LibGDX: Art Assets Couldn't Load Dependencies, because Access Denied

Tags: java, android, libgdx, assets

I'm trying to load a few images into an AssetManager, but my problem is that when they can't be loaded because of dependancies and denial of access... I have never encountered this before and other sources aren't very helpful.

All of this is taking place in the main project, not the Android version.

The strange thing is that a file at the same level as it, the nukeCount.png, is perfectly fine and can be used.

The code in question is here: 
https://github.com/EyeWumbo/libgdx_device_v1.1/blob/master/Device/src/device/textures/Textures.java

And the assets directory is here:
https://github.com/EyeWumbo/libgdx_device_v1.1/tree/master/Device

```
Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: Couldn't load dependencies of asset: data/art/game/UI/uibase/buttons/nuke
at com.badlogic.gdx.assets.AssetManager.handleTaskError(AssetManager.java:517)
at com.badlogic.gdx.assets.AssetManager.update(AssetManager.java:351)
at com.badlogic.gdx.assets.AssetManager.finishLoading(AssetManager.java:372)
at device.textures.Textures.loadArtAssets(Textures.java:104)
at menu.StateManager.moveToGame(StateManager.java:151)
at menu.StateManager.create(StateManager.java:65)
at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.mainLoop(LwjglApplication.java:130)
at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:110)
Caused by: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: Couldn't load dependencies of asset: data/art/game/UI/uibase/buttons/nuke
at com.badlogic.gdx.assets.AssetLoadingTask.handleAsyncLoader(AssetLoadingTask.java:119)
at com.badlogic.gdx.assets.AssetLoadingTask.update(AssetLoadingTask.java:89)
at com.badlogic.gdx.assets.AssetManager.updateTask(AssetManager.java:454)
at com.badlogic.gdx.assets.AssetManager.update(AssetManager.java:349)
... 6 more
Caused by: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: Couldn't load file: data/art/game/UI/uibase/buttons/nuke
at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.async.AsyncResult.get(AsyncResult.java:46)
at com.badlogic.gdx.assets.AssetLoadingTask.handleAsyncLoader(AssetLoadingTask.java:117)
... 9 more
Caused by: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: Couldn't load file: data/art/game/UI/uibase/buttons/nuke
at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Pixmap.<init>(Pixmap.java:140)
at com.badlogic.gdx.assets.loaders.TextureLoader.loadAsync(TextureLoader.java:72)
at com.badlogic.gdx.assets.loaders.TextureLoader.loadAsync(TextureLoader.java:41)
at com.badlogic.gdx.assets.AssetLoadingTask.call(AssetLoadingTask.java:69)
at com.badlogic.gdx.assets.AssetLoadingTask.call(AssetLoadingTask.java:34)
at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.async.AsyncExecutor$2.call(AsyncExecutor.java:65)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: Cannot open a stream to a directory: data\art\game\UI\uibase\buttons\nuke (Internal)
at com.badlogic.gdx.files.FileHandle.read(FileHandle.java:140)
at com.badlogic.gdx.files.FileHandle.readBytes(FileHandle.java:222)
at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Pixmap.<init>(Pixmap.java:137)
... 9 more
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: data\art\game\UI\uibase\buttons\nuke (Access is denied)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.badlogic.gdx.files.FileHandle.read(FileHandle.java:137)
... 11 more
```

Comment: The code and folders/files seem to be correct. But the stacktrace here doesn't match the code on github. It says Line 104 in the stacktrace, but it should be 108. Does it work when you just remove the entry with nuke.png? It somehow seems like the folder data/art/game/UI/uibase/buttons/nuke cannot be accessed.

Comment: I "fixed" the problem by replacing the asset with another copy from a friend's asset folder. I still don't know what caused this issue though...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I "fixed" the problem by replacing the asset with another copy from a friend's asset folder. I still don't know what caused this issue though...

Comment: Had same problem, it appeared to be related to files having lower case and upepr case letters, so on some OS's it mattered and on others it did not, and when generating pack it was messing up things, and sometimes having different names in "pack"(upper case versus lowercase)

Comment: @AvetisZakharyan I copied some random assets to my asset folder in android studio, and got the error. I copied the exact same assets moments later in the exact same way again, and everything worked. It literally was a random error, probably for some other reasons it didn't copy-paste well first time, or got corrupted/interrupted by some other means.

Answer (score 0):

Your file name contains uppercase letter if you should use all characters lower case this problem will solve.Because Android system get file name's lower case characters. I hope i explained well.